# How do I upload and manipulate excel file with Django?

Tags: python, django, excel, django-models

Ok,

I had a look at the UploadFile Class documentation of the Django framework. Didn't find exactly what I am looking for?

I am creating a membership management system with Django. I need the staff to have  the ability to upload excel files containing list of members (and their details) which I will then manipulate to map to the Model fields.

It's easy to do this with pandas framework for example, but I want to do it with Django if I can.

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use **xlrd** to read excel files

in client side you just submit a form with file input.

on server uploaded file stored on request.FILES

read file and pass it to xlrd then process sheets and cells of each sheet